# Jupyter notebook giving syntax error to codes

Tags: python-3.x, string, indexing, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Greeting everyone

Please what could be responsible for Jupyter notebook outputting Name error messages to my lines of codes it had correctly run just some moments ago? Please someone should assist me.
[Name Error on Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVcSF.png)

I am taking a Python course on Udemy and was keenly following the instructor's codes on indexing string

```
s = 'abcdefghijk'
s[3]
```

Expected Result: `d`

The first time I ran the code, it produced the expected result above but after some while, I ran my lines of codes again but this time I kept getting Name Error for all lines of codes which had run correctly before.

Comment: they are in different code blocks and you ran the second block before the first...

Answer (score 0):

the jupyter notebook runs code sequentially and tells you on the side the order of which they (the code blocks) are run.

So in your example i can see that you tried to run `s[3]` (line 9) before you created the the string `s = 'abcdefghijk'` (line 43).

[image]

So the notebook would not have know of that variable (not defined) until you created it.

if they were in the same code block, then it would have worked.
[image]